# image upload in web server fails

Tags: php

In my local host it is working. But in webserver  it is not uploading the image.
I cant find the reason for that. The path is correct.

```
$img_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

 $file_src = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];

   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file_src);
```

Am getting the file. It is also sure. Then what can be the reason???

Comment: check your file permission

Comment: echo $_FILES['file']['error']; this and know the error

Comment: echo $file_src and know that  path are rights ?

Comment: There is a very strong chance that this is a file permission problem. The directory $file_src must be writeable by the user assigned to the web server (often `apache` or `www-data`).

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/danielzen/utp7j/